# Azure Powershell Get-AzWebAppSlot AppSettings is empty always

Tags: azure, powershell

I'm trying to Get-AzWebAppSlot that works fine. It returns the data, but AppSettings are always empty. I've checked the slot on portal azure, and it has the app settings.

Here the code:
[image]

Here is the result
[image]

Here is the app settings on portal azure
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Make sure you are using the `-Slot` parameter.

`Get-AzWebAppSlot -ResourceGroupName "test" -Name "mywebapp" -Slot "Staging"`

https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/powershell/module/az.websites/get-azwebappslot?view=azps-6.4.0